# Restart Apache and MySQL When they Go Down

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, apache

How can I write a bash script so that when either my Apache server or MySQL go down, they automatically restart on their own?

Right now, I'm having to manually execute these commands whenever they go down:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

It's annoying to be having to check my websites and restarting the servers, is there a bash script I can use to check every 5 minutes if both of these servers are running?

Comment: cron. what happens if your test fails, they are up, and u nuke them

Comment: Create wrapper for service that keeps track of pid and restarts? See mysqld_safe.sh if you need an example.

Comment: Alternatively, `pacemaker`/`corosync`/`heartbeat`! (Likely Overkill)

Comment: I guess I'd want to figure out why they're crashing, as that should basically never happen.  You ought to scour the logs at the time they fail to see if there's anything interesting there. These are extremely robust services that should be capable of running for months or years without a hiccup. `apache2` (as opposed to `httpd`) and explicit `/etc/init.d` in your commands suggest this is a Debian or Ubuntu system, correct?

Comment: I agree with Michael - you should not be restarting it - you are setting yourself up for a corruption on the database.   You could as an emergency (days) look into upstart or systemd to handle restart on crash, but again, I really advise against it.  Apache really should not crash, nor should mysql.  There is a much larger problem.

Comment: Michael: yes, it's Ubuntu.

Comment: Can anyone point me to a simple script that will check every 5 minutes if my Apache server is down and if it is, restart it?

Comment: @RickHelston, seriously: find the *problem*.  These services should literally run for months or years and *do not just die*.  You are almost certainly trying to run them with too little system memory, a notorious problem when running them together on the same machine (which is not usually a good idea, since their resource demands tend to peak in parallel): http://serverfault.com/a/560554/153161

Comment: Rick, if restarting apache when it dies is really what you want, why not adapt the mysql script I pointed to and make it do just that?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
if [[ ! "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" =~ "active (running)" ]]
then
    echo "MySQL restarted" | mail -s "yourwebsite server mysql restarted" yourmail@gmail.com
    sudo service mysql start
fi

if [[ ! "$(/usr/sbin/service apache2 status)" =~ "active (running)" ]]
then
    echo "Apache restarted" | mail -s "yourwebsite server Apache restarted" yourmail@gmail.com
    sudo service apache2 start
fi
```

save above bash as mysqlfix.sh

give proper permission

```
chmod +x mysqlfix.sh
```

add a cronjob

crontab -e

```
*/1 * * * * /root/mysqlfix.sh
```